# How can you run Xamarin Android Player from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

So I have Visual Studio 2015 installed along with Xamarin and the Android SDK, etc... After being frustrated by the slowness of the default AVD(Android Virtual Device) I took some advice to get the Xamarin Android Player.

I went through the installation process and can run a virtual device instance by itself but I cannot get this to open from Visual Studio such that when I compile my Android app's code it opens in the Xamarin Android Player instead of the slow default AVD opening.

See image below:
[image]

Comment: Once you launch android player it should show up in that drop down you highlighted. Not sure what would stop visual studio from detecting your android player.

Comment: You can open up the the android command prompt (there is a button in the toolbar in VS). type in: "adb devices" and see if the XAP one shows up... if it doesn't type in "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server" which will reboot the adb server to detect it. If worst comes to worst close VS and re-open.

Comment: acastr7, Thanks that solved it! It didn't show up the first time I tried this from then on I wasted hours searching the internet trying to find out a way to "install" XAP "into" VS. James, thanks for your response also, this will come in handy

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What I did was to open up my xamarin android player and then downloaded some of the devices and then restarted VS 2015. This came up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old now, but thought it was worth pointing out for others that come across this question like I did. It looks like we may be better off using an emulator that isn't the Xamarin Android Player as it has been depreciated.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/

[image]